# Most simple way to setup forwarding proxies using AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, proxy, terraform

I'm currently looking at a task where I guess that I'm lacking some networking background, despite it sounds rather simple in theory:

For collaboration we're using a dedicated repo server located in Europe. It frequently happens that colleagues need to sync their workstate with this server (or even do a full sync of a branch at times). However, some of our colleagues are located in north america and asia, and if they have to do a full sync (which is > 200 GB). This can take almost forever because of the long route.

I've been asked to setup 2 proxy servers, one in North America and one in Southeast Asia, to help speed up the connection.

The idea is simple: Instead of connecting to the real IP of the repo server, they should use the IP of the proxy, which then forwards the communication to the actual repo server.

So I wanted to quickly set this up using Terraform and AWS, but the more research I am doing, the more I am getting confused:

- Will I need to setup a VPC with instance(s) in each region?
- If yes, What kind of proxy service do I need to install on them and how should it be configured?
- Alternative 1: Can I maybe just do that using AWS (elastic) Load Balancers instead? If so, how to set it up?
- Alternative 2: How about setting up a VPN network instead with entry point instances in both regions and the dedicated server being joined into that VPN network? And have the colleagues just dial in via VPN and access the repo server via internal IP? However that sounds quite overkill to me...

In all of these cases, I think I'm probably also missing a key element to actually ensure the bandwidth will be better in the end.

I'd appreciate if someone could provide some guidance here. Maybe I just failed at using google properly. :-)

Comment: 200 GB of AWS bandwidth between regions will run you $4 a pop. Is any of this cacheable? Could you replicate the storage to a server in each area (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-region-replication-for-amazon-s3/) so there's less inter-region traffic and people pull from a local endpoint?

Comment: The full sync is a rather rare case; usually we have avg traffic of ~10-20G max per day, so this would not be that problematic.

Actually the repo server software (Perforce) supports setting up proxy instances: (http://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r16.2/doc/manuals/p4dist/chapter.proxy.html)
However setting this up and administering it would cause additional overhead, plus it will still have to sync with the main server, which will still be slow if not optimized. But yes that is a backup option in case costs for traffic would explode.